# Get a photo with most likes in facebook album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can i get the photo with the most likes in a facebook album and when i get for a single album how can i count for example for last 7 created albums the picture with the most likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option to sort Graph API results as far as I know. So, **either** you count and sort the results of the Graph API request

```
GET /{album_id}/photos?fields=album,id,likes
```

yourself (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/photos#read), **or** if you have a Graph API v2.0 app, you can use the following FQL to retrieve the most liked `photo` of an `album`:

```
select object_id, like_info.like_count from photo where album_object_id="{album_id}" order by like_info.like_count desc limit 0, 1
```

where `{album_id}` is your actual `album_id`.

Concerning the 7 last created albums, you'd have to query first for the most recent albums, and then execute the above request for each of them (because FQL doesn't support `GROUP BY` statements). You can use the Batch API to run these 7 requests in parallel (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests).

If you put some effort in the Batch call generation, you could even do the whole 8 requests in one, if you use the referencing feature. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#operations